# NodeJs caching with Redis

Tags: node.js, caching, redis

I am new to NodeJs and Redis and would like to implement the caching feature proposed by Redis.

I am trying with the below query but I'm not sure how to go forward after a lot of google searches. The query is as per below :

```
module.exports = function(app) {

app.get('/api/data', function(req, res) {
 Subjects.find({}, {'_id': 0, 'school_state': 1, 'resource_type': 1, 'poverty_level': 1, 'date_posted': 1, 'total_donations': 1, 'funding_status': 1, 'grade_level': 1}, 
  function(err, subjectDetails) {
   if (err) 
   res.send(err);
    res.json(subjectDetails); 
  });
 });
 }
```

Can you please advise how to go forward?

Comment: What is Subjects? Mongoose model?

Comment: Yes, subjects is mongoose model

Comment: Where is your redis connection? Should just be redis.set('all', JSON.stringify(subjectDetails)).

Comment: My redis connection is made as per below var redis     = require('redis');
var client      = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost'); My main doubt is about how to check if the records exist  in the cache and eventually render prior to querying the database. I googled around but I'm not sure how to go forward with. Thank you for your help on this issue

Comment: You have to first query cache/redis before mongo, here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/janajri/f7e7d509a7d4c9045073

Comment: @Yousef, any chance you can post this as the answer to help future users?

Comment: @Daniel I posted the gist as requested

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution from the above gist that was posted. API request passes a callback to getSubjects. getSubjects checks the redis cache prior to making a database call for the data.

```
var redis = require('redis')


var cache = redis.createClient()

var subjectQueryParams = {'_id': 0, 'school_state': 1, 'resource_type': 1, 'poverty_level': 1, 'date_posted': 1, 'total_donations': 1, 'funding_status': 1, 'grade_level': 1}

var getSubjects = function(done) {
     cache.get('subjects', function(err, data){
        if(err) return done(err)
     if(data)
       return done(null, JSON.parse(data))
     Subjects.find({}, subjectQueryParams, function(err, results) {
       if(err) return done(err)
       if(results) {
         cache.set('subjects', JSON.stringify(results))
       }
       done(null, results) // no results
    })
  })
}

app.get('/api/data', function(req, res) {
 getSubjects(function(err, data) {
   if (err) return res.send(err);
   res.json(data); 
});
```

With async / await (assuming cache.get and Subjects.find return a promises)

```
const redis = require('redis')
const cache = redis.createClient()

const subjectQueryParams = {'_id': 0, 'school_state': 1, 'resource_type': 1, 'poverty_level': 1, 'date_posted': 1, 'total_donations': 1, 'funding_status': 1, 'grade_level': 1}

async function getSubjects() {
     const data = await cache.get('subjects') 
     if(data)
       return JSON.parse(data)
     const results = await Subjects.find({}, subjectQueryParams)
     if(results) {
        cache.set('subjects', JSON.stringify(results))
     }
     return results
  })
}

app.get('/api/data', async function(req, res) {
   const data = await getSubjects()
   res.json(data)
})
```